# Link to external site in php

Tags: php, hyperlink, external

I am trying to link to an external site.

where as $location outputs the URL (e.g. www.siteurl.com)

How do I make the outputted url a link and not just text

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just `echo` out the anchor tags

```
echo '<a href="'.$location.'">Click</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try below code for other external site in new tab

```
echo '<a href="'.$location.'" target="_blank">Link name</a>';
```